# When the module $M$ is divisible, the radical of $M$ equals $M$.

Tags: modules

> Problem: Let $_{\mathbb{Z}}M$ be an abelian group. Prove that:
>   If $_{\mathbb{Z}}M$ is [*divisible*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisible_group), then [$\operatorname{Rad} M$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_a_module)$=M$.

My ideas: we know that 
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Rad}M&=\bigcap\{K\leq M\mid K \text{ is maximal in }M \}
\\[4px]
&=\sum\{L\leq M\mid L\text{ is superfluous in }M \}.
\end{align}
Since the maximal submodule must be proper submodules, why $\operatorname{Rad} M=M$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $N$ is a maximal submodule of $M$.

Then $N$ is a proper submodule of $M$, hence $M \setminus N \ne \large{Ø}$.

Let $x \in M \setminus N.$

Since $N$ is maximal, $M/N$ is cyclic of order $p$, for some prime $p.$

It follows that $pM \subseteq N.$

Since $M$ is divisible, there exists $y \in M$ such that $py = x.$

But then $py \in pM \implies py \in N \implies x \in N,\,$ contradiction.

Therefore $M$ has no maximal submodules.

Thus, $\operatorname{Rad}M$ is the empty intersection (of submodules of $M$).

It follows that $\operatorname{Rad}M = M,\,$ as was to be shown.

Comment: If M has no proper maximal submodules ,Rad M should be 0,isn't it?further more M at least has a maximal submodule,that is 0.

Comment: zero module is maximal in M iff M is simple.

Comment: But a divisible abelian group is never simple unless it's the zero group.

Comment: Yes ,you are right.Thank you very much!